# Cannot see My account link in header on one of the category page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, myaccount

I have one category page which contains static block, I don't see My account and shopping cart in the header when I visit that page. See https://prnt.sc/r4y5n3
However, it is appearing on all other pages see https://prnt.sc/r4y5zs
I checked there is no CSS issue. 
What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Are both pages is category pages?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: can you check browser inspect elements. html show my account and cart ?

Comment: Check this link https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/knowledge-base/coupon-deals.html

Comment: There are js error in console that the reason, check https://prnt.sc/r5iyx9 and these error are not there on homepage